# No se han especificado los valores para algunos parametros requeridos

Tags: c#, oledb

estoy cargando un libro de excel usando OleDB, conecto y todo pero al momento de hacer la consulta entonces me arroja un error de que requiere parametros, pero no estoy pasando ningun parametro en la consulta.

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Ruta + "; Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"");
        cn.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select idcliente, idaportacion, monto from [Hoja1$] order by idcliente", cn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Prueba primero con `select * from [Hoja1$]`, es posible que no reconozca el nombre de los campos

Comment: Me trae el mismo error @RogerTorné

Comment: Agrega la excepcion completa para poder verla.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba en añadir al datatable columnas con los nombres de los valores de la consulta:

```
table.Columns.Add("idcliente")
table.Columns.Add("idaportacion")
table.Columns.Add("monto")
```